# Better way to check if window got actually closed

Tags: c#, wpf, windows

I would like to know if there is a better way than the following to check if the window got closed, or if a `Closing` cancled the closing procedure?

Here we go with my way:

```
var window = Application.Current.Windows.FirstOrDefault(x => x is FooWindow);
if (window != null)
{
    var gotClosed = false;
    window.Closed += (sender, args) => gotClosed = true;
    window.Close();
    if (gotClosed == false)
    {
        //Close got cancled, by closing...
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

From checking the .NET source, I'm not too sure that `IsDisposed` is safe. There don't seem to be a lot of safe options though. The one I have been using so far without issues is checking the `Visibility` property for `Visible` after closing.

A cleaner approach might be creating your own class and overriding `OnClosing()` or `OnClosed()` though:

```
protected override void OnClosing(System.ComponentModel.CancelEventArgs e)
{
    // Fires Closing event
    base.OnClosing(e);

    if (!e.Cancel)
    {
        // Window was allowed to close.
        // Set IsClosed = true or something like that
    }
}
```

There you can store the result in a property for example.

Answer (score 1):

I'm not sure it's better than your solution, but after calling `window.Close()` the property `IsDisposed` gets true. So, you can check it:

`if(window.IsDisposed)
{
   ....
}`